# How do I return (or print) a maximum number of hits from a statement?

Tags: python, loops, max

i have a for loop statement that returns umpteen million amount of numbers (ok exagerating a bit :).  how do i tell it to stop at the 50th result?

seams simple enough.  can't find a solution though.  can't use a lot of modules i see being used here.  even in basic math module we are restricted in what we can use.  so if possible please be very elementary in your answer.  thank you

using python.

e.g. range(0, 99999999) or f = 's' * 50000000

.. print only 50 results of these two.

Comment: Something like `range(9000)[:50]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to give you the index along with the value in a for loop. Even though I'm using lists here, I'm assuming that you are using some kind of iterator, otherwise you could just slice the list like `mylist[:50]`.  E.g., this would print up to the 50th entry.

```
for i, val in enumerate(range(600)):
    if i == 50:
        break
    print i
```

Or to print every 50 values

```
for i, val in enumerate(range(600), start=1):
    if i % 50 == 0:
        print val
```

You could use a while loop too.

```
i = 0
some_iterator = iter(range(600))
while i < 50:
    print some_iterator.next()
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
In [22]: import itertools as it

In [23]: for elem in it.islice(it.count(), 50):
   ....:     print elem,
   ....:     
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

Note that [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) is an *infinite* iterator.

Another possibility is to use [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
In [24]: for elem in it.takewhile(lambda x: x < 50, it.count()):
   ....:     print elem,
   ....:     
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

Obviously I'm assuming you are working with iterables and not sequences. If you have sequences then you can simply use the built-in slice syntax:

```
sequence[:50]
```

But this requires to first build the complete sequence, which may or may not be feasible in your case.

Comment: well done,  enumerat is the first tool most grok but islice is well worth the effort to learn.